# Getting java.io.IOException: JMX connection closed. when manually ran repair on pratition range of a keyspace using nodetool

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, nodetool

[2016-07-06 17:28:51,593] Lost notification. You should check server log for repair status of keyspace operations
Exception occurred during clean-up. java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
error: JMX connection closed. You should check server log for repair status of key                                                                       space operations(Subsequent keyspaces are not going to be repaired).
-- StackTrace --
java.io.IOException: JMX connection closed. You should check server log for repair                                                                        status of keyspace operations(Subsequent keyspaces are not going to be repaired).
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.RepairRunner.handleNotification(NodeProbe.ja                                                                       va:1485)
        at javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport.handleNotification(Unkn                                                                       own Source)
        at javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport$SendNotifJob.run(Unknow                                                                       n Source)
        at javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport$1.execute(Unknown Sourc                                                                       e)
        at javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport.sendNotification(Unknow                                                                       n Source)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.sendNotification(Unknown Sourc                                                                       e)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.access$1200(Unknown Source)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RMIClientCommunicatorAdmin.got                                                                       IOException(Unknown Source)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RMINotifClient.fetchNotifs(Unk                                                                       nown Source)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$NotifFetcher.fetchOneN                                                                       otif(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$NotifFetcher.fetchNoti                                                                       fs(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$NotifFetcher.doRun(Unk                                                                       nown Source)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$NotifFetcher.run(Unkno                                                                       wn Source)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientNotifForwarder$LinearExecutor$1.run(U                                                                       nknown Source)